# Typescript - Create Type for dynamic keys

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have written a `ts type` for typechecking my code and Im facing few issues. Here is my type and sample data..

**TYPE:**

```
type TObjectsFieldsMap = {
  [objectName: string]: {
    _chosen: boolean; // ERROR 1
    [fieldName: string]?: { // ERROR 2 when fieldName is made optional
       _chosen: boolean; // ERROR 3
    };
  };
};
```

**Errors of above ts type:**

```
1. '_chosen' of type 'boolean' is not assignable to 'string' index type '{ chosen: boolean; }'

2. Property or signature expected. (this is occurring when adding "[fieldname: string]" as optional(?:)

3. 'boolean' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

**sample data:**

```
{
  dynamicObj1: {
    _chosen: true,
    dyanmicField11: {
       _chosen: false
    },
    dyanmicField12: {
       _chosen: true
    }
  },
  dynamicObj2: {
    _chosen: false,
    dyanmicField21: {
       _chosen: false
    }
  },
  dynamicObj3: {
    _chosen: false,
  }
}
```

It would be grateful, if someone points the error and its reasons and it will a good learning curve for me.. TIA !

Comment: There's no specific type in TypeScript that lets you add an "exception" to a string index signature.  There's no way to say "all strings except for `_chosen`".  See the answers to the linked question for more information, and possible workarounds, all of which are somewhat annoying.  If your non-`_chosen` properties all started with the prefix `"dynamic"` you could do this, but I'm assuming that you weren't trying to communicate that they all start with a common prefix (right?)

Comment: yeah you are right.. `objectName` is completely random and does not start with any prefix..

Comment: So then there's nothing much better than the workarounds mentioned in the answer to the other question.  If you can refactor so that the dynamic properties don't have to coexist with static properties in the same object, it will be much easier.  Otherwise you have a bunch of somewhat-usable alternatives.  Good luck!